# Can't scroll top top in scrollable BottomSheetDialogFragment + Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, scroll, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I encountered the following behaviour with BottomSheetDialogFragment:

1. I open bottom sheet with scrollable content
2. Scroll down
3. When I try to scroll up, bottom sheet closes instead of scrolling up (scrolling up and bottom sheet closing gestures are the same)

I need the opposite behaviour - on swipe up I need to scroll up, and only when it can't scroll any further, bottom sheet should close. How can I change this behaviour?

Here's the video with this bug: https://youtube.com/shorts/SO1JafvvgMw?feature=share

Code:

```
@Composable
fun PrivilegeBottomSheetContent() {

    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .verticalScroll(scrollState)
    ) {
        // Elements
    }
}
```

Bottom sheet:

```
class PrivilegeBottomSheetDialog : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View = ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
        setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
        setContent {
            PrivilegeBottomSheetContent()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in [Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/touch-input/pointer-input/scroll#parent-view-child-compose)

Here's the solution:

```
@Composable
fun PrivilegeBottomSheetContent() {

    val nestedScrollInterop = rememberNestedScrollInteropConnection()
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .nestedScroll(nestedScrollInterop)
    ) {
        // Elements
    }
}
```

In my BottomSheetDialogFragment I use XML layout with ComposeView and NestedScrollView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
        android:id="@+id/composeView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```